# gae-boilerplate existing blob not showing

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, python-2.7, routes

Error does not display image with the following url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/serve/CrObzPCoJfjG4ESUUb0hjw==
```

Image does exist in the blobstore can be checked in admin
My route 
[Dope on redirect routes](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/routes.html#webapp2_extras.routes.RedirectRoute)

```
RedirectRoute('/serve/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]', handlers.ServeHandler, name='ServeHandler'),
```

My code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

import urllib

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    logging.info("SERVE " + str(resource))
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    self.send_blob(blob_info)

class FetchHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
blob_info = upload_files[0]
logging.info("FOUND blob info" + str(blob_info))
self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())


class ImageHandler(BaseHandler):
    @user_required
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        user_session = self.user
        user_session_object = self.auth.store.get_session(self.request)
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/fetch/')    

        user_info = models.User.get_by_id(long( self.user_id ))
        user_info_object = self.auth.store.user_model.get_by_auth_token(
            user_session['user_id'], user_session['token'])

        try:
            params = {
                "upload_url": upload_url,
                "user_session" : user_session,
                "user_session_object" : user_session_object,
                "user_info" : user_info,
                "user_info_object" : user_info_object,
                "userinfo_logout-url" : self.auth_config['logout_url'],
                }
            return self.render_template('image.html', **params)
        except (AttributeError, KeyError), e:
            return "Secure zone error:" + " %s." % e
```

Comment: The regex you are using is incorrect so the url is not being mapped correctly try something like [a-zA-Z0-9-_].

Comment: @Tkingovr thanks for the reply, the redirect is from the _ah/upload not saving and redirecting see   The failed redirect url:

Comment: i had to use <> as in /serve/<resource> it doesnt allow naked strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might be on this line:

```
 self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())
```

According to the following recent changes assuming you did update appengine to the latest release:

```
The Blobstore service now returns the created filename instead of the blobKey when using Cloud Storage [link][1]
```

Have a look at the [recent release notes](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) and the changes that came with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think they URL that you are providing to the `create_upload_url` is the wrong one, since you are defining it like `/upload/`.

Add the forward slash in the end and it should work:

```
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload/')
```

Comment: THanks! . I tried that and the redirect failed with a 500 error INFO     2013-02-18 15:56:13,267 dev_appserver.py:3103] "GET /fetch/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2013-02-18 15:56:17,651 dev_appserver.py:724] Internal redirection to /upload/
ERROR    2013-02-18 15:56:17,665 basehandler.py:114] 500 - list index out of range

Comment: @peterretief If that didn't work.. not sure how this framework works exactly.. never played with it.

Comment: thanks for having a look - it seems that datastore_v3.Put is failing with a permissions error (POST upload RPC) I don't know what they have done to break this but I am pulling my hair out !!!

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your code (form an earlier revision of your question) to some code I have working, I suspect that you might not want the trailing / on the `/upload/` route (i.e., use `/upload` instead.

I'm not familiar with `RedirectRoute`, though.

Comment: Thanks @Dave W. Smith I tried that variation of upload as well, my question has got into a bit of a mess I know but the answer really lies in something that has changed in the gae-boilerplate code - I should go back through the change logs and see what they did - the upload does actually work but there is a permission error when trying to display the image

Comment: Sometimes useful info ends up in application logs, available through the admin console (`/_ah/admin`) when you're using the development appserver.

Comment: INFO     2013-02-23 16:19:49,458 dev_appserver_blobstore.py:413] Upload handler returned 302

Comment: INFO     2013-02-23 16:30:21,180 dev_appserver_blobstore.py:413] Upload handler returned 405 this when it fails